# SSIS data import with resume

Tags: sql, ssis, azure-sql-database, data-transfer

I need to push a large SQL table from my local instance to SQL Azure. The transfer is a simple, 'clean' upload - simply push the data into a new, empty table.

The table is extremely large (~100 million rows) and consist only of GUIDs and other simple types (no timestamp or anything).

I create an SSIS package using the Data Import / Export Wizard in SSMS. The package works great.

The problem is when the package is run over a slow or intermittent connection. If the internet connection goes down halfway through, then there is no way to 'resume' the transfer.

What is the best approach to engineering an SSIS package to upload this data, in a resumable fashion? i.e. in case of connection failure, or to allow the job to be run only between specific time windows.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, in a situation like that, I'd design the package to enumerate through batches of size N (1k row, 10M rows, whatever) and log to a processing table what the last successful batch transmitted would be. However, with GUIDs you can't quite partition them out into buckets.

In this particular case, I would modify your data flow to look like Source -> Lookup -> Destination. In your lookup transformation, query the Azure side and only retrieve the keys (SELECT myGuid FROM myTable). Here, we're only going to be interested in rows that don't have a match in the lookup recordset as those are the ones pending transmission.

A full cache is going to cost about 1.5GB (100M * 16bytes) of memory assuming the Azure side was fully populated plus the associated data transfer costs. That cost will be less than truncating and re-transferring all the data but just want to make sure I called it out.

Answer (score 3):

Just order by your GUID when uploading. And make sure you use the max(guid) from Azure as your starting point when recovering from a failure or restart.